# I have DTO for each json payload. I get the payload through http post request. I get two payloads but how to combine them to final payload

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, lambda, mapping

I have DTO for payload1, payload2 and payload3. 
    How to get the payload3?
    using payload 1 and payload 2.
How to establish the mapping between the data models?

DTO 1

```
public class DataRequestModel {
private DataValue data; //some example
private long  timestamp;
@Data
public static class DataValue {
private Value1 value1;
private Value2 value2;
}
@Data
public static class Value1 {
    private long val;
}
@Data
public static class Value2 {
    private long val;
}
}
```

Data Model 2

```
public class Guid{
private string guid; 
}
```

Datamodel 3

```
 public class payload{
 private String guid;
 private long longvalue;
 private long timestamp;
 }
## Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class DataTransferController {
 List<Payload> payload;
 @PostMapping("/list")
 public void data(@RequestBody DataRequestModel dataRequestModel){
```

**Not sure how to do from here...**

```
       for(Payload temp: payload){
         temp.getLongValue()=dataRequestModel.getData().
         }
 }
 }
```

**These are the structure of the JSON**
1.JSON payload1

```
  {  
  "data":{  
 "value1":{  
    "val":30
 }, "value2":{  
 "val":20
 }
  },
 "timestamp":155501523
}
```

2.JSON payload2

```
       {  
       "guid":[  
       "/value1",
       "/value2"
       ]
       }
```

3.JSON final payload (to be sent)

```
     [  
     {  
     "guid":"/value1",
     "longvalue":30,
     "timestamp":155501523
     },
     {  
     "guid":"/value2",
     "longvalue":20,
     "timestamp":155501523
     }
     ]
```

My code for generating payload 3 is

```
   @RestController @RequestMapping("/users")
 public class DataTransferController 
    { 
    List<Payload> payload; @PostMapping("/list")

    public void data(@RequestBody DataRequestModel dataRequestModel)
    { 
    Not sure how to do from here... for(TimeseriesPayload temp: timeseriesPayload)
{ 
temp.getLongValue()=dataRequestModel.getData().
 } 
}
 }
```

Comment: show the code that you have tried

Comment: @RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class DataTransferController {
    List<Payload> payload;
    @PostMapping("/list")
    public void data(@RequestBody DataRequestModel dataRequestModel){
Not sure how to do from here...
        for(TimeseriesPayload temp: timeseriesPayload){
            temp.getLongValue()=dataRequestModel.getData().
        }
    }
}

Comment: please update the code in the post not in the comment

Comment: Okay done! I didn't include the getters and setters in the code

Comment: check the posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need for loop to do this, in the `public void data` create `List<Payload>`

```
public void data(@RequestBody DataRequestModel dataRequestModel)  {

  List<Payload> list = new ArrayList<>();
  // first object
  Payload payload1 = new Payload();
  payload1.setGuid(//set value);
  payload1.setLongValue(dataRequestModel.getData().getValue1().getVal());
  payload1.setTimestamp(dataRequestModel.getTimestamp());
  list.add(payload1);
  // second object
  Payload payload2 = new Payload();
   payload12setGuid(//set value);
  payload2.setLongValue(dataRequestModel.getData().getValue2().getVal());
  payload1.setTimestamp(dataRequestModel.getTimestamp());
  list.add(payload2);
```

And then finally return `List`

Comment: I have 10 values in the payload1 and 10 values in the payload2... Do I have to add to the list every time...  Is there any simpler way?

Comment: since your `DataRequestModel`  in not in structure like array, i don't see any easier way than this @bharathisurisetti

Comment: Can we use the lamba function for dynamicmapping?